# Modelling problem

Tags: estimation, system-identification, maximum-a-posteriori-estimation, signal-identification

Considering a finite-length impulse response $h[n]$ of length $M $ (which amounts to considering $h[n] = 0,$ for $n \geq M$). The data model, with additive disturbance, is then written as:
$$y[n] = y_M[n] + \epsilon[n]$$
where

$$y_M[n]= \sum_{k=0 }^{ M-1} h[k]x[n-k].$$

We seek to estimate the impulse response $h[n]$, i.e., the parameter vector $h = \big[h[0], h[1], ..., h[M-1]\big]$, from the observed data $y[0], y[1], ..., y[N-1] $ and known inputs $x[0], x[1], ..., x[N-1]$ (we assume that the input signal is causal, i.e., $x[n] = 0 $ for $n < 0$).

1. What is the output of the system $y[n]$ when an impulse is placed at the input? Show that we can deduce an estimator $hri$ of the impulse response, specifying its bias and covariance matrix.
2. Is the model $y_M[n] $ linear with respect to the parameters?

This is what I did, but I don’t know how to write it in a matrix form

$$\cases{
y_M [n] = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}h[k]\mu[n-k]\\
y[n] = h[n] + \epsilon[n]}$$

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: You say "estimator hri" -- do you mean something like $h_{ri}$, or is "hri" an abbreviation for something?  Please edit your question to put the math into math, or to spell out your abbreviations.

Comment: Is the additive disturbance truly not dependent on $k$?  I.e., is $y[k] = y_M[k] + \epsilon$ correct, or is it $y[k] = y_M[k] + \epsilon[k]$?

Comment: @TimWescott I have corrected it